# programmatically press tab in webbrowser control C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, keypress

I want to press tab key programmatically. I used this code:

```
private void BrowserPage_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  webBrowser.Select();
  webBrowser.Focus();
  PreviewKeyDownEventArgs ee = new PreviewKeyDownEventArgs(Keys.Tab);
  webBrowser_PreviewKeyDown(sen, ee);
}
```

but in web browser the focus is not moving to next control..

Comment: Just set the focus on the DOM element you want to have selected so you don't have to rely on the flaky keyboard simulation.  HtmlElement.Focus() method.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure webBrowser control has the focus and try the next line:

```
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
```

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx).

I hope it helps.

Comment: it didnt work.. i want to programatically press tab in inactive application sendkeys will send to only active applications

Answer (score 1):

So when the tab key is pressed you'd like to give focus to the web browser?

put your code in

```
private void ("what tab is benig pressed on")_KeyPress(object sender,    KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Keychars == keys.Tab)
    {
        webBrowser.Select();
        webBrowser.Focus();
    }            
}
```

I think keys.Tab should work if not try googling what the numeric value of the tab key is and put it in place of keys.Tab

where i put " what tab is being press on you'd run the key press on that...not the webBrowser

hope this helps sorry if my not correct i just spend 7 hours on an application of my own

**Update:** numeric value for tab is 9

Comment: it didnt work.. i want to programatically press tab in inactive application